# Trouble adding environment variables to $PYTHONPATH in linux

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

So I want to add some code to my python path the code is located in $HOME/eon on my machine. I was told to add:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/test:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$HOME/test/bin:$PATH
```

to ~/.profile. However this does not work for me. When I type those two lines into the terminal I do add the test folder to my python path but only temporarily. I have also tried adding the two lines to my ~/.bashrc file but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing works fine on my system, so it's possible you forgot to "tell the system" to use the new version `~/.bashrc`

Here is the output from my terminal after adding your lines to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
/home/amit/test/bin:/home/amit/test/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/amit/bin
```

The changes are not reflected. However, after

```
[amit@amit ~]$ source ~/.bashrc
```

I get:

```
[amit@amit ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/amit/test/bin:/home/amit/test/bin:/home/amit/test/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/amit/bin
```

Comment: Not sure how but I had multiple instances of bashrc up at some point because vim told me I had a swap file for it. Once i deleted the swap file everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add them in `~/.profile`
2. Save and exit
3. Do `source ~/.profile` to make changes effective for the current bash

If you are still having problems, you can add `echo 'hello world.'` to your `.bashrc` and see if it prints it when you open a new terminal to see if your system runs `.bashrc` as it should be.